# Flutter: How to turn printed output into a List<String>?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code which, when pressed, returns a string which I would like to convert into a List variable to use in a dropdown menu.

I have been using the print function to check that I am getting the correct data from Cloud Firestore but I am unsure of how to use the Firebase.Instance to produce the List variable.

Code:

```
                          child: RaisedButton(
                          child: Text('Submit Survey'),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await Firestore.instance
                                .collection('MySurveys')
                                .document('FirestoreTestSurvey')
                                .get()
                                .then((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                              print("${document.data['a_ge_vi']}");
                            });
```

Output:

```
I/flutter (13548): [Conservatives, Labour, Liberal Democrats, SNP, Plaid Cymru, Brexit Party, Other, I would not vote]
```

How would I go about using the Firestore.instance to make a List Variable which I could then use in a dropdown menu when the app loads up.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: `document.data['a_ge_vi']` is already a `List`. That's why you are able to print it out like that in the first place. (Assuming, of course, it isn't actually a `String` with that content.)

Comment: @Abion47 excellent news! How would I get that list into a variable which I could then use in 

DropdownButton(
items:

Comment: @davidjeffery You can simply cast the value to a list, i.e. `List<String> list = document.data['a_ge_vi'];`

Answer (score 0):

try doing

> document.data['a_ge_vi'][0];

if it returned a value, then it's already a list.

you can simply use as drop down menue by saying

> YourList.map((item) => DropDownMenueItem( value : item, child : Text(item))

Comment: Where would this go?

Comment: @davidjeffery in your Dropdown widget, it has a parameter 'items' that needs a list of DropDownMenueItem widgets , by doing this you're mapping the list of strings to list of these widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this way

```
                       onPressed: () async {
                        await Firestore.instance
                            .collection('MySurveys')
                            .document('FirestoreTestSurvey')
                            .get()
                            .then((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                         List<String> stringList= document.data['a_ge_vi'];
                          print(stringList);
                        });
```

Update put it inside `initState()`

```
@override
  void initState() {
     super.initState();
                    await Firestore.instance
                            .collection('MySurveys')
                            .document('FirestoreTestSurvey')
                            .get()
                            .then((DocumentSnapshot document) {
        List<String> stringList= 
           document.data['a_ge_vi'];
      print(stringList);
  }
```

Comment: I have made a mistake - I don't want this to be created onPressed, I want it to already exist when the user opens the screen. How do I do this?

Comment: This is the code I have now
`
void getData() async {
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('MySurveys')
        .document('FirestoreTestSurvey')
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot document) {
      List<String> a01List = document.data['a_ge_vi'];
      print(a01List);
    });
  }
`

Comment: put it initState() if it help upwote

Comment: Thank you - but I keep getting the error 'undefined name 'stringList'' in my DropdownButton items field, as well as the error 'the declaration initState isn't referenced. 

I have inserted the code just under the @override of my build widget

Comment: On further inspection, whenever I try to return something from my `void initState()` it shows up an error about the data being null.